# Geting started with OOP in Python - Question

Tags: python, oop

Im new at OOP in Python, and I have a question.
Hope you can help me :D
Here is the full script.

```
class Book:
def __init__(self, isbn, title, author, publisher, pages, price, copies):
    self.isbn = isbn
    self.title = title
    self.author = author
    self.publisher = publisher
    self.pages = pages
    self.price = price
    self.copies = copies

def display(self):
    print(self.isbn, self.title, self.price, self.copies)

def in_stock(self):
   return True if self.copies > 0 else False
        
def sell(self):
    if self.in_stock():
        self.copies -= 1
        print("Number of copies now:", self.copies)
    else:
        print("No stock at the moment")
def listas(self):
    lista = [book1, book2, book3, book4]
    for book in lista:
        book.display()

    jack_books = [book.title for book in lista if book.author == 'Jack']

    print(jack_books)
book1 = Book('957-4-36-547417-1', 'Learn Physics','Stephen', 'CBC', 350, 200,10)
book2 = Book('652-6-86-748413-3', 'Learn Chemistry','Jack', 'CBC', 400, 220,0)
book3 = Book('957-7-39-347216-2', 'Learn Maths','John', 'XYZ', 500, 300,5)
book4 = Book('957-7-39-347216-2', 'Learn Biology','Jack', 'XYZ', 400, 200,6)


book1.display()
book2.display()



book1.in_stock()
book2.in_stock()

book1.sell()
book2.sell()
book3.sell()
```

And I just want to show the items with the display() funct while the "for" is running
Here

```
def listas(self):
lista = [book1, book2, book3, book4]
for book in lista:
    book.display *### I know It's wrong but it is exactly as the solution the teacher gives*
```

As I said in the comment, it is exactly as the solution, but I don't know what Im missing, or maybe I have to create something or call it below

Like did here

```
book1 = Book('957-4-36-547417-1', 'Learn Physics','Stephen', 'CBC', 350, 200,10)
book2 = Book('652-6-86-748413-3', 'Learn Chemistry','Jack', 'CBC', 400, 220,0)
book3 = Book('957-7-39-347216-2', 'Learn Maths','John', 'XYZ', 500, 300,5)
book4 = Book('957-7-39-347216-2', 'Learn Biology','Jack', 'XYZ', 400, 200,6)


book1.display()
book2.display()



book1.in_stock()
book2.in_stock()

book1.sell()
book2.sell()
book3.sell()´
```

Sorry if I've expressed myself bad.
Hope you could understand. Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to *call* the method, not merely reference the method, so `book.display()` instead of `book.display`

Comment: Yeah I wrote it with "()" in the full script but forgot to put them when trying to explain.
It is not doing anything either.
And no errors

Comment: I don't think you can pre-define the `book1, book2, etc` before establishing their class instances, it should be after their individual `book1 = Book()` objects initalization at the end of the script.

Comment: Because you never call that function, see my answer

Comment: @FishingCode well, you *can* as long as those names exist in the global scope when you call that methd.

Comment: @BenjaF you aren't calling `. listas` anywhere. It isn't clear to me *what you are expecting*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Agreed, but that global def is probably not the intention or a good idea.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's not advisable to take that approach, it should follow a *top-down* structure.

Comment: @FishingCode I never claimed it's *advisable*. But you definitely *can* do that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I called it again after this, just passed the book list as parameter, but the elements are no being read.

Comment: @BenjaF that doesn't make any sense. please provide a [mcve], including any outputs, and / or error messages

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, I don't know how to explain it, and don't want to bother you all. Of course you are trying to help me, I really appreciate it, but I think I'll keep trying things just to make myself clear then.
PD: And not errors or output showing.

Answer (score 1):

The indentation makes this very unclear. Also you are defining a method which has the books in it which you are defining before you define the books which is illadvised at best.

I *think* what you are trying to do is this but the question isn't super clear

```py
class Book:
    def __init__(self, isbn, title, author, publisher, pages, price, copies):
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.pages = pages
        self.price = price
        self.copies = copies

    def display(self):
        print(self.isbn, self.title, self.price, self.copies)

    def in_stock(self):
       return True if self.copies > 0 else False
            
    def sell(self):
        if self.in_stock():
            self.copies -= 1
            print("Number of copies now:", self.copies)
        else:
            print("No stock at the moment")

def listas(books):
    for book in books:
        book.display()

    jack_books = [book.title for book in books if book.author == 'Jack']

    print(jack_books)
```

You need to then define a list of books and pass them to the function listas()

```py
book1 = Book('957-4-36-547417-1', 'Learn Physics','Stephen', 'CBC', 350, 200,10)
book2 = Book('652-6-86-748413-3', 'Learn Chemistry','Jack', 'CBC', 400, 220,0)
book3 = Book('957-7-39-347216-2', 'Learn Maths','John', 'XYZ', 500, 300,5)
book4 = Book('957-7-39-347216-2', 'Learn Biology','Jack', 'XYZ', 400, 200,6)
book1.sell()
book3.sell()

listas([book1,book2,book3,book4])
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Okay I did that, but is not reading the elements of the list "books" as parameter, or the function is not being executed.

Comment: It works for me, it prints Learn Chemistry and Learn biology. What is your output?